# Bound on the product of functions in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let X be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f, g,$ and $h$ be real valued functions in $L^2(X)$. Consider 
$$\| fgh\|_{L^1(X)}.$$ The hope is to get an upper bound in terms of $\|\cdot\|_{L^2(X)}$ of the individual functions; however, I don't actually think this is possible. Any idea on how close one can get? Here are some upper bounds, does anyone else have suggestions?

Cauchy-Schwarz\Hölder gives
$$\| fgh\|_{L^1(X)} \le \|f\|_{L^2(X)}\|gh\|_{L^2(X)}
=\|f\|_{L^2(X)}\|g^2h^2\|^{1/2}_{L^1(X)}
\le\|f\|_{L^2(X)}\|g\|_{L^4(X)}\|h\|_{L^4(X)}$$

Or if one of the functions is in $L^{\infty}(X)$ we have
$$\| fgh\|_{L^1(X)} \le \|f\|_{L^2(X)}\|gh\|_{L^2(X)}
\le\|f\|_{L^2(X)}\|g\|_{L^2(X)}\|h\|_{L^\infty(X)}$$
Also, I suppose we could use some similar arguments for arbitrary $p$ and $q$ satisfying $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Martin's answer below gives a clean counterexample, but for as best as you can do, there is a generalization of Holder's inequality, which states that $||fgh||_1 \leq ||f||_p||g||_q||h||_r$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} +\frac{1}{r}=1$. See the wiki on Holder's inequality under "Generalization." This may not be quite what you're after, but it may be useful.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, this should be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$
f=g=h=\frac1{t^{1/3}}\,1_{(0,1]}^\vphantom{2}(t).
$$
Then
$$
\|f\|_2=\|g\|_2=\|h\|_2=\left(\int_0^1\frac1{t^{2/3}}\,dt\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt3,
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}fgh=\int_0^1\frac1{t}\,dt=+\infty.
$$

Comment: The integral of $t^{-3/4}$ converges on $(0,1)$. Maybe instead take $t^{-1/3}$ in your original definition?

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for a very clean counter example.